# Google Image Search using hidden information of the file?

Tags: google-image-search

I know there's hidden information called EXIF, but I think this is something else and here is why. Try, for example, searching in Google images "INFO". You will probably find this picture in some of them:

```
http://www.visitkoege.com/sites/default/files/styles/galleries_ratio/public/asp/visitkoege/diverse/info.jpg?itok=6VrRt9UQ
```

Try to download this picture (or if you can't find it you can download any other). Now, upload this image by drag-n-drop to Google Image Search and you will notice the text "selfie props". What the heck is this?! Where did this info come from? It's not in the EXIF. Or perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing related to any information IN the file. It's, basically, Google who is trying to associate word with the images. Or by recognition of the image or by search in his data with which words the same kind of images has been linked on others website. 
Sometimes the information provide is really good and... sometime it's not really what it should be. Like in your case, Google "thinks" that, this "INFO" image is related somehow to a selfie props.